# Prove $x_n = \frac{n-3}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is monotonic starting from some $n_0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, monotone-functions

I'm having some difficulties with the following problem:

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \frac{n-3}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}
> $$ 
>   Prove $x_n$ is a monotonic sequence starting from some $n_0$.

I've applied the following test to prove that. Suppose $\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} > 1$

$$
\frac{n-3}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}}{n-2} > 1 \iff \\
\iff \frac{n-3}{n-2} >\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}}
$$

Now squaring both sides (this is BTW where i think things get wrong):
$$
\left(\frac{n-3}{n-2}\right)^2 >\frac{{n^2+1}}{{(n+1)^2+1}} \iff \\
\iff (n-3)^2((n+1)^2+1)>(n^2 + 1)(n-2)^2
$$

After some algebraic transformations one may get:
$$
3 n^2 - 5n - 7 < 0
$$

Now find $n_0 \ge 1$ starting from which the inequality holds:
$$
n_{1,2} = \frac{5 \pm\sqrt{109}}{6}
$$

So from this $n \approx2.57 < 3$. So for $n \ge 3$ the inequality holds. **But that's not true!** From the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hbcrkch8sh) it's crystal clear that $x_n$ is monotonically increasing $\forall n \ge 1$.

Where did things go wrong? I believe it's a consequence of squaring the inequality, but can't see how it went wrong.

Comment: Hint: what happens when $2 \le n < 3$?

Comment: Even ignoring the potential division by zero, the squaring step introduces a $\implies$ (instead of the $\iff$ at all other steps). So nothing is wrong with concluding "IF the quotient is $>1$ and $n\ge 0$, THEN $n\ge 3$"

Comment: x_0=-3.x_1=-2/√2,x_3=0, increasing .For n>3 start proving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n\geq3$ we obtain:
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{n-2}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+2}}-\frac{n-3}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=$$
$$=\frac{2(3n^2-5n-7)}{\sqrt{(n^2+2n+2)(n^2+1)}((n-2)\sqrt{n^2+1}+(n-3)\sqrt{n^2+2n+2})}>0,$$
which says that our sequence increases for $n\geq3$.

Comment: Isn't $x_n$ ($a_n$ in your answer) still monotonic for $n \in [1, 2]>$

Comment: @roman It was typo. I fixed. You look for the proof that $x$ is  monotonic from some $n_0$. No? I have a proof that your sequence decreases for all natural $n$, but it's another problem.

Comment: Well, your answer indeed shows that for $n\ge 3$. I'm just wondering why $n = 1,2$ are missed.

Comment: @roman Because for $n=1$ the denominator is negative. We need another way. But it's another problem already.